# Multiple EF Migrations - what ties a migration to a given context/configuration?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, internals

I have an assembly which contains two `DbContext`s both of which use EF Migrations generating explicit migrations with `Add-Migration`. I have a whole sequence of migrations on one datacontext, and (at the moment) a single migration on the other.

Looking through the code, I'm confused what exactly ties a given migration to the context and/or configuration that it affects. I see no references anywhere in the migration class, its auto-generated partial, or its resx of the "owning" configuration.

Comment: EF6? They should be in different folders and name spaces. The name space is the context key in the __MigrationHistory table. Migration configuration class should derive from DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContextNumber1>.

Comment: @SteveGreene wait, they *should be*? When I created this it let me put both in the same folder, there is no docs anywhere I've seen that indicate that is the case.

Comment: There are multiple ways to configure. [Different folders with parameterized commands](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/entity-framework-6-code-first-migrations-with-multiple-data-contexts).  [Two contexts, two contextkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx). Does your project have a Configuration.cs for each context?

Comment: Yup, it does. But all migrations are in the same folder

Comment: It's a good question then on how EF matches the migration files with the configuration class if they are in the same folder. IAC, if the context key exists it should be ignored for already applied migrations. Maybe Brice from the EF team will respond with a better answer.